# IntelliJ converting java project into a javafx project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I have an existing java project but want to be able to add javafx components into the project, but right now when I try to run the code I get an `Exception in Application start method` because IntelliJ is not copying the fxml files from the src directories to the target directories, and therefore they aren't being found by getClass().getResource("MyFile.fxml"). How do I get around this, do I need to make a new project and import my source. Is there a specific way to do this or do i just paste all my files into a new JAVAFX project?

Comment: Make a new `JavaFX` project and add your logic accordingly.

Comment: Do you get error something like : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228487/javafx-location-is-not-set-error-message or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755630/javafx-location-is-not-set-error?rq=1 ?

Comment: Please make sure that the resource patterns under Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler include the ".fxml" pattern