# JavaFX - Exception in Application

Tags: java, exception, javafx, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I am trying to create a JavaFX program, and every time I try to run my code I am getting an exception - I'm not entirely sure what it means though ...

My code:

```
 package com.PickingList.ui;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Main extends Application {

        private Stage stage;

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
               Scene scene;
               FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("./TelaLogin.fxml"));
               Parent root = loader.load();      
               stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
               stage.setTitle("Login");
               stage.show();

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

I'm using Eclipse to create the project, and I'm getting the following error:

```
 Exception in Application start method
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
        at com.PickingList.ui.Main.start(Main.java:19)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    Exception running application com.PickingList.ui.Main
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWiMO.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFX Location is not set error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228487/javafx-location-is-not-set-error-message)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/TelaLogin.fxml"));
```

Assuming that, your folder structure looks like:

> /src/TelaLogin.fxml